# ¿Cómo lograr una versión vectorizada de esta función?

Tags: r, funciones, programación-funcional

Revisaba algunas cosas sobre matrices y la distancia de Mahalanobis y se me ocurrió hacer una pequeña función que rankea las observaciones de cada columna de una matriz. A continuación el código:

```
test <- matrix(c(78.17,70.25,75.33, 86.08,54.97, 43.63,18.04,
0.3,1.4,0.5,1.5,0.7,0.2,0.1,3,5,5,8,9,10,2), ncol=3)
test

rank_columns <- function (x) {
    y <- matrix(ncol=ncol(x), nrow=nrow(x))    
    for (j in 1:ncol(x)) {
    y[,j] <- rank(x[,j])
        }
        return(y)
    }

rank_columns (test)
```

La función regresa una matriz con las dimensiones originales de la matriz de entrada y las observaciones rankeadas:

```
rank_columns(test)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    3  2.0
[2,]    4    6  3.5
[3,]    5    4  3.5
[4,]    7    7  5.0
[5,]    3    5  6.0
[6,]    2    2  7.0
[7,]    1    1  1.0
```

Como muchos de ustedes saben, no soy muy bueno utilizando la familia `apply`, por lo que me preguntaba si existe alguna forma de vectorizar la función para optimizar su funcionamiento cuando se trabaje con matrices de mayor tamaño.
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test_ranked <- apply(test, 2, rank)

El 2 en el segundo argumento hace que la función de aplique por columnas.

Comment: Gracias. Tanto lío para algo tan sencillo. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Alejandro, en primer lugar la respuesta que te ha dado Javier Ascunce din duda es una forma adecuada de resolverlo, pero quiero extender un poco más la explicación.

En R se repite hasta el cansancio lo de no usar ciclos explicitos (`for`, `while`, `repeat`) sino usar funciones `*apply`, es decir ciclos implícitos. Esto por que:

- El código suele ser mucho más compacto, lo cual por lo general hace menos confuso el mismo
- En algunos casos, dependiendo del código, suele haber mejoras en la performance

Te aclaro que en realidad no estamos hablando exactamente de "vectorizar", tu función ya estaría "vectorizada", es muy óptima, ya que solo estaría usando un ciclo por columna.

En tu ejemplo, dónde buscas "aplicar" la función `rank` a cada columna de una matriz, y asumo que buscas obtener una matriz similar a la original, la forma más sencilla de aplicar un loop implícito es:

```
apply(test,2,rank)
```

o en su versión más explicita:

```
apply(X = test, MARGIN = 2, FUN = rank)
```

Es decir, ingresa en este caso la matriz, y usando `MARGIN = 2` es decir que tomamos las columnas (`MARGIN = 1` sería por fila), a cada columna entonces, aplicaremos (`FUN = rank`) la función `rank()`.

Otra forma es usar `sapply()`, que es algo más parecido a lo que estás haciendo:

```
sapply(1:ncol(test),function(col){rank(test[,col])})
```

En este caso iteramos sobre cada columna de la matriz y aplicamos el `rank` sobre un recorte de la matriz correspondiente a la columna.

¿Que ocurre con la performance? veamos, hagamos una prueba con una matriz de 10.000 filas y probemos 1000 veces cada función:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(100)
ncols = 3
nrows = 10000
test <- matrix(runif(nrows*ncols), ncol=ncols)

mi <- microbenchmark(
     m <- rank_columns(test),
     m <- apply(test,2,rank),
     m <- sapply(1:ncol(test),function(col){rank(test[,col])}),
     times = 1000L)

autoplot(mi)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Interesante, las tres formas de hacer lo mismo tienen una performance muy parecida, mas allá que `apply()` tiene mayor dispersión de valores, se podría decir que no hay ninguna significativa ganadora, de hecho, tu `rank_columns()` hasta podría ser un "pelín" más rápida.

Mas allá de del rendimiento, sin duda, resolver varias líneas de código en una sola es una mejora significativa que vale la pena aprovechar siempre que se pueda.

Comment: Muy interesante. Gracias como siempre, Patricio.